# pokkst/litecoinj message verification problem - Address.fromKey() returning wrong address

Tags: litecoin, bitcoinj, java

I have a problem with java library `pokkst/litecoinj`. I am using the regular `bitcoinj` library to verify signed messages with success. As `pokkst/litecoinj` is a fork of `bitcoinj` I have expected it to work in same or close manner.

I have a method:

```
private boolean isSignatureValid(NetworkParameters params, String address, String message, String signature) {
    try {
        Address signingAddress = Address.fromString(params, address);
        ECKey key = ECKey.signedMessageToKey(message, signature);
        Address addressFromKey = Address.fromKey(params, key, signingAddress.getOutputScriptType());
        return signingAddress.equals(addressFromKey);
    } catch (SignatureException | AddressFormatException exception) {
        LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage());
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("Address cannot be null!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Given data (this is just a test wallet so I do not worry about it):

```
params -> MainNetParams.get();
address -> ltc1qhlnfnzc6djz92ylf89cvsw7jzyl98hx79ye5a5
message -> test-test-test-test-test
signature -> IC6AcfBff2TA1brwVneXPFtUyHCu1hffTvcaTyNM+i5IbNc7UgNIA4bdVu3mpr0awTsaIK7lpY4O5pS4+/SJDUw=
```

Important: this address and signature are generated using `Electrum-LTC` wallet, cause I haven't found any other litecoin wallet that will allow me to sign messages.

When I run a test against this method, i see that `addressFromKey` is different than `signingAddress` and it's value is `ltc1qewvcwvf9ln6uypme8wskmg5khqwpss7v9zcrj7`

My code for Bitcoin message verification is very similar, and it is working fine.

I don't have access to the wallet keys, a wallet address, message and signature is all I have.

What am I doing wrong? May this be a bug in the library? Or could it be something wrong with Electrum-LTC?

Answer (score 2):

Method

```
ECKey.signedMessageToKey
```

calls:

```
formatMessageForSigning(message)
```

which uses constant BITCOIN_SIGNED_MESSAGE_HEADER_BYTES
defined:

```
private static final String BITCOIN_SIGNED_MESSAGE_HEADER = "Bitcoin Signed Message:\n";
private static final byte[] BITCOIN_SIGNED_MESSAGE_HEADER_BYTES = BITCOIN_SIGNED_MESSAGE_HEADER.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I changed to:

```
BITCOIN_SIGNED_MESSAGE_HEADER = "Litecoin Signed Message:\n";
```

And your code worked with signatures generated by Electrum-ltc.